# connect html file with css file in the pycharm

Tags: python, html, css, django, pycharm

[image: the picture]

i am new user django-pycharm and i want to create a html/css template in the pycharm.
my proplem is in the pycharm i cant to connect html file with css file.
if i run that files with the classic way out of the pycharm its ok but i cant to connect in the program.

my connect line in the txt files

```
link href="templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: your `css` and `html` file should be at same directory

Comment: This problem does not have anything to do with the programming language compiler. when you just type a file name in HTML, that file should be at the same directory as you html file... if you want to set another directory you can type full address or a tree mode address like `css/file.css` or `../file.css` .... read more about rules

Comment: That is just not even vaguely true. The "HTML file" here is a Django *template*, which is rendered by a web framework; it is not served by the same means as the CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your static files inside the `static` directory inside your app. Then you should be able to access them using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your template.

Django Templating is a little different than usual HTML/CSS. You need to put some efforts into learning how the template works and how the static files are served.

Answer (score 2):

in django, you need to set up things a little bit, so that django (in local machine) or your web server (if you deploy the code to production) will find and render the static files (they are: css, images and js files) correctly.

[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) you read how you set it up first in django itself.

at the end, you will have something like this in your html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<link href="{% static 'css/templatemo_style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

so, your static files  dont live directly in the same folder where html files live, but in their own folders, I normally call them `site-static`.

and here how you set up PyCharm with Django by the way :) http://www.django-tips.com/tip/how-to-setup-pycharm-for-django/31/

Answer (score 0):

There is a type there. The css link says: "templatemo" and the file is called "templatermo".

Answer (score 0):

your html code is wrong

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templatermo_style.css">
```

also check file name, your css file's name is `templatermo_style.css` not `templatemo_style.css`

I recommend you to use static files instead of usual way, check other answers

Answer (score 0):

So what I found to work is...

So basically what I did was I manually typed up until I got to the href link and then pressed control+spacebar and it automatically brought up my style.css link for me and did the directory itself. Maybe that would work.