# How can I link my external css file to my html file in Pycharm?

Tags: python, html, css, pycharm

Inside the project folder, I have created both the html and CSS file under 'venv' library root folder.
html file name - index.html
CSS file name - styles.css

code that I used to link CSS:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">`

This does not seem to work. Need help.

Comment: See this [connect html file with css file in the pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581214/connect-html-file-with-css-file-in-the-pycharm)

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not available in PyCharm Community but it will work perfectly in the Professional edition. Also, if you face a problem with the static file use `href="{% static "static/d.css"%}"` and change the [setting.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407499/django-not-loading-static-files-pycharm/44408825)
You can see how to [add it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/style-sheets.html#ws_css_documentation_lookup_check_compatibility_inspection). I run the code below in `PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Professional edition)`.

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

h1 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="d.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I switched to atom ide for now because I am a beginner and I do not have the fundamentals in place but your response might help me later

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but check it.
you can add the folder what the css file is found.
like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../root/styles.css" type="text/css">`